# Is there a simple way to generate a multidimensional array in Rcpp and export that array to R

Tags: r, arrays, rcpp

I'm looking for a simple way to build a 3D array using Rcpp and make that array accessible in R. I'm still very new to Rcpp and c++ coding in general, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my source code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


int d[5][5][5] = {0};

// [[Rcpp::export]]

int fit(){ 
  for (int X = 0; X < 5; X++){
    for (int Y = 0; Y < 5; Y++){
      for (int Z = 0; Z < 5; Z++){
        d[X][Y][Z] = X + Y + Z;
      }
    }
  }
return d;
}
```

The idea being I could assign fit() to an element in R (say D), and be able to call from locations in that array.

I realize I could just make "fit" a function of x, y, and z; but for my purposes, having the array in R works much faster.

Again, any help would be super appreciated.

### Edit

Thank you for the help Dirk,
One thing I'm still struggling with is running the loops. When I run this loop:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector rcpp_matrix(){

  IntegerVector v = IntegerVector(Dimension(2,2));
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        v(i,j) = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
    }
  }
  
  // Return the vector to R
  return v;
}
```

It works as intended. However, when I try to span out to three dimensions, like so:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector rcpp_matrix(){

  IntegerVector v = IntegerVector(Dimension(2,2,2));
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++){
        v(i,j,k) = (i + 1) * (j + 1) * (k + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Return the vector to R
  return v;
}
```

I get errors:

```
file10c2d06d0b.cpp: In function ‘Rcpp::IntegerVector rcpp_matrix()’:
file10c2d06d0b.cpp:14:16: error: no match for call to ‘(Rcpp::IntegerVector {aka Rcpp::Vector<13>}) (int&, int&, int&)’
   14 |         v(i,j,k) = (i + 1) * (j + 1) * (k + 1);
      |                ^
```

Is there some other aspect I'm missing?
Thank you again.

Answer (score 7):

Vectors are key in R, and an array is just a vector with 2-d dimension attribute:

```
> v <- 1:12
> dim(v) <- c(3,4)
> v
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
>
```

So we can also do 3-d:

```
> dim(v) <- c(2,3,2)
> v
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    9   11
[2,]    8   10   12

>
```

and so on.  And *that is the exact same thing in Rcpp* as seen e.g. here from a unit test snippet:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector integer_dimension_ctor_3(){
    return IntegerVector( Dimension( 2, 3, 4) ) ;
}
```

which we can test quickly:

```
> Rcpp::cppFunction("IntegerVector ivec3() { return IntegerVector(Dimension(2, 3, 4));}")
> ivec3()
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0

>
```

All that said, I recommend you look into Armadillo 'Cubes' and what you can do from RcppArmadillo -- likely more fully featured.

*Edit:*  Here is much simpler Armadillo variant of your approach, using a `cube<int>` aka `icube`:

##### Code

```
#include <RcppArmadillo/Lightest> // new 'lighter' header

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::icube make3dvec(){
    arma::icube v(2,2,2);
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++){
            for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++){
                v(x,y,z) = (x + 1) * (y + 1) * (z + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return v;
}

/*** R
make3dvec()
*/
```

##### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/75036466/answer.cpp")

> make3dvec()
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    4
[2,]    4    8

>
```

Comment: Thank you; that is very helpful. I looked a little into Armadillo Cubes and need to spend some more time understanding the syntax.

Comment: This is all excellent stuff. For me, this brings up the shock that one gets when using the function (apparently) designed to identify an R vector. `is.vector(v)` returns `[1] FALSE`. The lesson I learned was that the `is.vector` function is not very useful and that one should learn to use `is.recursive` (which vectors are not) or `is.atomic` (which they are) instead. What we generally think of as R vectors are atomic vectors. `is.atomic(v) [1] TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I found a solution, albeit a little convoluted, to the specific issue I was having.

```
sourceCpp(code = "
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
    
// [[Rcpp::export]]

IntegerVector fit(){ 
  int d[2][2][2] = {0};
  IntegerVector V = IntegerVector(Dimension(8));
  int Count = 0;
  for (int X = 0; X < 2; X++){
    for (int Y = 0; Y < 2; Y++){
      for (int Z = 0; Z < 2; Z++){
        d[X][Y][Z] = (X + 1) * (Y + 1) * (Z + 1);
        V(Count) = d[X][Y][Z];
        Count = Count + 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return V;
}
")
```

Which creates a vector for `fit()`, which I can use in R to get the array I want, vis-a-vis:

```
array(fit(),dim=c(2,2,2)
```

Thank you again for the help. This is speeding up my original model quite a bit.

Comment: Please make yourself a nice cup of coffee or tea and re-read the documentation and examples on Armadillos `cube`.  I'll edit my answer to show what you likely wanted.